# Conflict with use of the same id and class name on an element in Jquery? Any pros and cons?

Tags: jquery, html, class

I had a couple of situations where when using the same name for id and class on an element caused some problem. Putting it another way, certain problems went away when I used different names for id and class on the same element. The code is too long and uses a lot of JS to reproduce here. It is possible that the source of the problem was elsewhere. However, having experienced it on more than one occasion, I am now hesitant to use the same name for an id and class on the same element, even when it appears to be more readable. Is my hesitation unfounded? I think that there is nothing in the HTML/CSS specs to prohibit such naming but are there some Jquery or other bugs which cause such problems?

Extending the same question: What are the pros and cons, technical or quasi-technical, of using the same name for id and class on an element?

**EDITED:**

This is not a question related to reusing the same Id. It is a question related to the following:

```
   <div id="name1" class="name1">...</div>
```

With class="name1" used on other elements but id="name1" NOT used on other elements. The key question is the use of the same name for id and class.

Comment: As long as the ID is unique I see no reason to have issues with classnames that are the same as an ID

Comment: Is this the old _IDs must be unique_ problem? If no, it depends how IDs and classes are used in your document.

Comment: _"I am now hesitant to use the same name for an id and class on the same element, even when it appears to be more readable"_ - When is it more readable? Classes are (pretty much by definition) for use with multiple elements, which means a descriptive class name isn't likely to make a good id... Anyway, assuming unique ids I'm not aware of any technical problem with using the same name for id and class.

Comment: @nnnnnn. I appreciate your comment and totally agree with your explanation but sometimes a class name may be an ideal choice to identify  an element, for example the parent of some of the elements using the class names.

Comment: Each tool has it's own usage, you are free to use (_technically unique_) IDs and classes the way you want, if your document is valid and there is a conflict in your JavaScript, the logic behind your code is _broken_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same id will lead to unexpected results in your code, since ids are supposed to be unique.

When it comes to classes, a similar thing applies if your class is not supposed to be re-used. Sometimes people want to select one particular element using a long selector, like `table#foo .bar .baz.biz`. Instead, I reccomend creating a descriptive new selector specifically for the element we're selecting, such as `menu-item-list`.

I would suggest namespacing classes. Suppose you have a "Menu" component, then all classes on that component are prefixed `mn-`, like so:

```
<div class='mn-container'>
    <span class='mn-title'>Item 1</span>
    <div class='mn-item'>Item 1</div>
    <div class='mn-item'>Item 2</div>
    <div class='mn-item'>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

That'll help you avoid class name collisions.

Comment: Sorry, you did not understand my question. I am talking about the situation as in: <div id="name1" class="name1">...</div>. I am not talking about reusing id="name1" again. I am aware of the issues there.

Comment: I don't see a reason why you would need an `id` that's equal to either the `name` or a `class`. If that's the case you might want to consider creating another class and using _that_ as a unique identifier of sorts. Avoiding `id` helps you to avoid issues like CSS selector specificity and allows you to re-use (class) names, if necessary

Comment: I appreciate your viewpoint and that is a valid answer deserving an upvote... to use a unique class name instead of an id but my question still is what if... if the id and class name is the same, are there known problems? The general feedback here is useful. It supports your answer which is to avoid the conflict in the first place.